# Apply GPU Clock Speeds on Startup

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I have an NVIDIA GTX 760 graphics card that I overclock. I already have coolbits set up properly, and I have a stable overclock. I want to know if there is a way to set the overclocked frequencies on startup. Right now, I have to manually enter the values into this screen:
[image: NVIDIA X Server Settings]

Everything I could find on the internet said to run `nvidia-settings` from a terminal, and set the frequencies using the 'GPU3DClockFreqs' attribute. When I try this, it tells me that the attribute is deprecated, and no longer supported. I've also tried auto-loading the configuration from .nvidia-settings-rc, but this file doesn't contain the overclocking options.

Is it possible to do this anymore, or has Nvidia completely locked it down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open *Startup Applications* and add a new entry that runs the following command:

> nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:0]/GPUGraphicsClockOffset[3]=50" -a "[gpu:0]/GPUMemoryTransferRateOffset[3]=200"

This will set the Graphics Clock Offset to 50 and the Memory Transfer Rate Offset to 200 on startup. If any of these values is too high, the system might crash after logging in!